# Finding a byte-pattern in some memory area

Tags: c++, memory, pattern-matching

I want to search some memory range for a specific byte pattern. Therefore, my approach is to build a function

```
void * FindPattern (std::vector<byte> pattern, byte wildcard, 
    void * startAddress, void * endAddress);
```

using the Boyer-Moore-Horspool algorithm to find the pattern in the memory range.

The `wildcard` byte stays for some specific byte which should be treated as a wildcard. 
So - for example - if `wildcard` is `0xCC`, every `0xCC` in `pattern` will be a wildcard.

The function should return the start of the memory range, where the pattern was found the first time.

My question is now: is there some similar function already done in the most common libraries or do I have to implement this for my own?

Comment: What does "wild-card" here mean? In some interpratations, the wild card could mean zero-or-more match, in other definitions it could mean one-or-more match. Please clarify your definition.

Comment: wild-card is an exactly-one match in this case. So, if the pattern is 0x1337f00d and the wildcard is set to 0x37, it should match 0x13??f00d with ?? being an arbitrary byte.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore%E2%80%93Horspool_algorithm) on BMH has an implementation. I think that Boost xpressive is also based on (a variant of) BMH.

Comment: The questino was more like if there is such a function in `windows.h` or some similar standard library.

Comment: As far as I know there is not but take a look at Boost's xpressive.

Answer (score 1):

No, it seems there isn't even a function like 'strstr' but for raw memory. Let alone wildcards!

Comment: Hmm... Wouldn't `std::search` work as `strstr`? Not that I suggest it as a replacement to gnu libc's `memmem`, but it exists and, perhaps, works ;-)